# Can Clearcase findmerge name elements it reports as having been skipped due to not being visible in the target view?

Tags: clearcase

I am performing large (i.e. many change sets, many elements per change set) propagations between software release streams.  Occasionally, Clearcase findmerge reports

> cleartool: Warning: Some change set elements were skipped because they were not visible in the target view.

I've read up on the root cause of this warning and understand it.  **What I am looking for is a means to have Clearcase report on the names of the skipped elements.**  When an element has been skipped, I need to manually dig into the issue to see if further work is required.  However, I cannot currently determine which elements I need to examine, since Clearcase is not naming them.

As I mentioned at the outset, I am dealing in large propagations, so the effort to attempt to manually find the skipped elements is very high and would not be necessary if Clearcase/findmerge could name the elements it warns about.

Answer (score 0):

`findmerge` means non-UCM merge, right? (Although you can use `findmerge` to merge change sets between UCM stream too...)

In every merge I seen, the only way to get that kind of information (which means more often than not a file, initially meant to be merged, has been rmname'd in the source branch, as mentioned in "[About handling elements that are not visible](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.doc/cc_main/about_elements_not_visible.htm)") is by parsing the logs of the findmerge (or of the `cleartool deliver` or `rebase` for UCM)

In short, that warning is mentioned at the *end* of the merge, but the actual files skipped could be listed *during* the merge (grep on '`skipped`').

Comment: I am using findmerge to merge changesets between UCM streams.  My specific command takes this form

Comment: I am using findmerge to merge changesets between UCM streams.  My specific command takes this form: `cleartool findmerge <changeSetName> -fcsets -nc -type d -log <logFileName> -abort -merge`, and the resultant log file (for those rare cases when an element is skipped) contains only the text `# Some change set elements were skipped because they were not visible in the target view.`  Note that additionally, I subsequently run a variant of the command for all types, which is meant to capture "files", and even that command produces a log file with only the warning text and nothing else.

Comment: @gawtrox It would be interesting to try a cleartool deliver (instead of findmerge), just to check if the output contains more information relative to the skipped files.